# How to put minor ticks in completely custom locations in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, customization, axis-labels

Say I want to add minor ticks to my x axis at custom locations equivalent to this command for major ticks: `plt.xticks([1,2,3])`.

I have tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,4,9]
plt.scatter(x,y)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator([1.1, 1.9, 2.5])
```

but that throws an error because the last command probably needs a ticker object, not a list in the argument. Any pythonic way to go about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to add the following line and turn on the `minor` flag to `True`

```
ax.set_xticks([1.1, 1.9, 2.5], minor=True)
```

[image]